# Java generics overriding method

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I'm new to using generics (very late to the party, I know), and aren't sure if what I am trying to achieve is possible, and if so, how.

OK, this is a contrived example of what I am try to achieve, that hopefully shows the pattern without any clutter:

```
// Pet and Cats
interface Pet { }
interface Cat extends Pet { }
class TabbyCat implements Cat { }

// Pet food and cat food
interface PetFood<T extends Pet> { }
interface CatFood extends PetFood<Cat> {}
class DryCatFood implements CatFood {}
class WetCatFood implements CatFood {}

// PetBowl
interface PetBowl<T extends Pet> {
    public void addFood(PetFood<T> food);
}

// CatBowl
class CatBowl implements PetBowl<Cat> {

    // this doesn't override method, why not?
    public void addFood(CatFood food) { }

    // this does
    public void addFood(PetFood<Cat> food) { }

}
```

So, basically what I am trying to do is make CatBowl implement PetBowl, but so that the addFood() method only allows CatFood to be added.

The only solution I have been able to come up with is:

```
...

// PetBowl
interface PetBowl<T extends Pet, F extends PetFood<T>> {
    public void addFood(F food);
}

// CatBowl
class CatBowl implements PetBowl<Cat, CatFood> {

    public void addFood(CatFood food) { }

}
```

However, in my non-contrived case there are more parameters, and this ends up making for a lot of boilerplate all over the place, so I'm hoping for a "neater" solution.

Comment: btw: I think your inheritance strategy is too complex, maybe you shouldn't use generics for "everything"...

Comment: yes, in this example, the use of generics on PetFood is somewhat redundant, and without it I probably would have spotted the actual issue sooner.  I think in the real situation my use of generics is more valid, though I do keep questioning it (I am conscious I may be overexcited by having a new toy to play with, and thus over using it).

Comment: ok, just wanted to highlight it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really linked to generics. The interface `PetBowl<Cat>` has a method `addFood(PetFood<Cat> food)`. So, any class implementing this interface should have such a method. `addFood(CatFood food)` is not acceptable because it doesn't allow adding any kind of `PetFoo<Cat>`, but only `CatFood`.

It's the same as if you had

```
interface A {
    void add(Object o);
}

class AImpl implements A {
    public void add(String s);
}
```

Obviously, `AImpl.add` doesn't override `A.add`, because it only accepts `String`s, and not `Object`s.

Comment: Ah, thank you, that explanation helps it make sense to me.  

CatFood only partially satisfies the requirements, as whilst it does extend PetFood<Cat> other classes may also extend that too, without extending CatFood.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the promise of the interface is that it can take a `PetFood<Cat>` so if you where able to make it take `CatFood` then you would limit the types the that your class can take ... and break the "interface".